# unable to run coffeescript app on nodejs. receiving exception

Tags: node.js, coffeescript

I have reacently started learning coffescript and was trying to fllow a simple tut. However when I try to run my app.coffee file using 
`coffee app.coffee` command, i keep on getting this exception;

```
PS C:\Users\Office\Workspace\node\blog-demo\coffeepress> coffee .\app.coffee
Error: In .\app.coffee, Parse error on line 1: Unexpected ' '
    at Object.parseError (C:\Users\Rishav\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\coffee-script\lib\coffee-script\parser.js:477
:11)
    at Object.parse (C:\Users\Rishav\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\coffee-script\lib\coffee-script\parser.js:554:22)
    at exports.compile.compile (C:\Users\Rishav\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\coffee-script\lib\coffee-script\coffee-
script.js:43:20)
    at Object.exports.run (C:\Users\Rishav\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\coffee-script\lib\coffee-script\coffee-scrip
t.js:79:34)
    at compileScript (C:\Users\Rishav\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\coffee-script\lib\coffee-script\command.js:175:29
)
    at fs.stat.notSources.(anonymous function) (C:\Users\Rishav\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\coffee-script\lib\coffe
e-script\command.js:150:18)
    at fs.readFile (fs.js:176:14)
    at Object.oncomplete (fs.js:297:15)
```

the coffee code is;

```
###
Module dependencies.
###
express = require("express")
routes = require("./routes")
http = require("http")
path = require("path")
app = express()
app.configure ->
  app.set "port", process.env.PORT or 3000
  app.set "views", __dirname + "/views"
  app.set "view engine", "jade"
  app.use express.favicon()
  app.use express.logger("dev")
  app.use express.bodyParser()
  app.use express.methodOverride()
  app.use app.router
  app.use express.static(path.join(__dirname, "public"))

app.configure "development", ->
  app.use express.errorHandler()

app.get "/", routes.index
http.createServer(app).listen app.get("port"), ->
  console.log "Express server listening on port " + app.get("port")
```

All my modules are the latest available till date.

Comment: have you tried removing the first three lines? the comment might just be breaking the parser there.

Comment: that was the first thing i tried. i also made sure that there are no indentation issues.

Comment: Just tried your code by clicking on edit below your question and copying the source code. Maybe you try the same. Don't forget the remove the first four spaces at the beginning of each line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is absolutely fine. Coffeescript however reserves keywords like `static` therefore if you run `coffee -c your_file.coffee` you will see your compiled js in `your_file.js`. Open it with editor and see what is wrong.

I am betting that the line `app.use express.static(path.join(__dirname, "public"))` gets compiled to somthing like `app.use(express["static"](path.join(__dirname,"public"))`. And that causes your error ;)

In future, if there is an error, compile the coffeescript first and then see the compiled version and see what is wrong with it.

Comment: thanks. This is an old question but following your suggestion fixed this issue for me.

Comment: I came across the same problem, so I documented the solution.

Answer (score 1):

I can run the code except for the routes file which you don't provide. I would try to recreate the file and see if there is anything corrupt with the actual file. I have sometimes had problem with Coffeescript files being malformed in indenting and it complains on something else.

The other thing I suspect is that there might be something wrong in your routes file.

Comment: oh the routes were created by express. this is the default express bootstrap. i first ran express demo-project. then converted all js files to coffee using js2coffee.